# Struct Padding in 32 Bit System

Tags: c, struct, padding

If there is a `C` structure like

```
struct abc
{
uint16_t                    port_no; //2 Bytes
uint8_t                     src_mac[6]; //6 Bytes
}
```

How would the compiler apply padding to align into 4 byte word on 32 bit sys:

Will it be

```
2 Bytes
Pad[2]
6 Bytes
Pad[2]
```

or

```
2 Byte
6 Byte
```

Comment: For your specific compiler (and version of it) you can use [`offsetof`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/offsetof) to find out. Note that it's highly implementation-specific.

Comment: Very often compilers have the struct packing mechanism

Comment: Even for a given compiler (version), the result is usually target-specific.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude THANKYOU!! That solves it :)

Comment: Also use `sizeof` to check for padding after the last member.

Comment: We are not a "do my homework" service.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude It's not so much implementation-specific. The alignment and padding is part of the architectures calling convention, the ABI of C object files if you will. Without common rules object files from different compilers couldn't be linked together. That still leaves a lot of 32bit systems to choose from though.

Answer (score 0):

That depends on the architecture of the system.

On a 32-bit MIPS your structure would have no 
padding whatsoever because `uint16_t` must be aligned 
even addresses and `uint8_t` need not be aligned at all.

However a variable of type `struct abc` would be aligned at 
even addresses thereby eventually forcing padding outside the 
struct (say, when `struct abc` is a member of a surrounding struct).

Comment: On ideone it is the same :-) https://ideone.com/Ywr2XP Linux 64 bits+gcc

Comment: The struct has size 8 (on most systems) so no padding outside the struct either.

Answer (score 0):

In C/C++ every type has a size and an alignment that can differ from architecture to architecture, kernel or even just C/C++ ABI.

Gcc provides a function `__alignof__` and C++11 has an `alignof(type-id)` function oficially that can be used to print the alignment requirement for a type. Plain C doesn't seem to have that but each type still has that property.

In memory every type has to be aligned to at least the alignment requirement and the compiler will insert padding into structs that ensure that is the case. The struct as a whole then has the largest alignment required for any of its members and a size that includes padding to a multiple of the alignment of the struct.

Generally an uint16_t has a 2 byte aligment requirement and chars a 1 byte alignment requirement. So th struct has a 2 byte alignment requirement and no padding is needed at all. Giving a total size of 8 byte for the struct.

But beware that the calling conventions for an architecture can require more alignment or padding for one reason or another.

Answer (score -1):

Padding is on by default. It inserts "gaps" into your structure automatically. It comes out as though there were a fourth intervening variable, like this:

```
struct abc
{
    uint16_t  port_no;    // 2 Bytes
    char pad_0[2];        // 2 Bytes
    uint8_t   src_mac[6]; // 6 Bytes
    char pad_1[2];        // 2 Bytes
}
```

Comment: Why the `char pad_0[2]`? The `uint8_t` doesn't have any alignment prerequisite.

Comment: The compiler adds 2 bytes to fill the 32 bits. If you want, you can also see it as `uint16_t` instead of 2 chars but in the end it's the same thing...2 bytes

Comment: https://ideone.com/Ywr2XP One of the most common architecturs (linux 64 bits + gcc) doesn't insert padding.

Comment: I don't know if the compiler may even reorder structure members to optimize